# Google App Script to trigger on Dropdown Change

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dropdown, spreadsheet, eventtrigger

I want to trigger the change event of dropdown (apps script), for example  using following code but not work, please tell me where is wrong, iam newbie

```
//Global Variable
let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let ws = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Rapot');
var baris = ws.getRange('AL7').getValue();
var kolom = ws.getRange('AL8').getValue();
let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Database');
function onEdit(e){
  let activeCell = e.range;
  let val = activeCell.getValue();
  let r = activeCell.getRow();
  let c = activeCell.getColumn();
  let wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();

  if(wsName === 'Rapot' && c === 3 && r === 7){
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(baris,kolom,41,14);
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();
  let targetRange = ws.getRange('D11:Q51');
  targetRange.setValues(sourceValues);
  }
```

Comment: Please note that onEdit only fires on user edits and it does not fire on edits caused by formulas or other scripts.

Comment: Try using `e.source.toast('label');`  in different locations in your script to assist you in locating problems.  And you can also use `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` to learn more about the event object which could speed up you code by eliminating the need for several function calls in your current code

Comment: What is in baris and kolom? What error do you get? Do some logging to make sure your if statement is good.